# Sync two different workbooks

Tags: excel

I have workbook I've been using for the last two weeks, but I need to sync & update it with another excel workbook, with updates that occur. This happens every 2 weeks - i.e if an item is updated what are the updated values.

I could this manually but because I'm using a filters it would take a lot of time to do that every 2 weeks. I thought there might be an easier way then doing this manually?

The common field between the two workbooks is opp id number. How could this be possible to sync?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use the field `id number` to bring updated values to your workbook. Check formula [VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need a fixed 2-weeks interval, you could simply use the **share workbook** function from Exel. This allows you multiuser editing and solves the problem of "which value is most recent". In case you need keep track of versions, you might use VBA code or a shell script to save backups.
(if you have a strict directionality (i.e. your changes need to be deployed every 2 weeks), then you can simply send and replace the remote workbook every 2 weeks, but I guess this is not the case)

Comment: thanks, but it wouldn't be sharing with any other users. this is just for my own workbook to keep track of changes as they occur very quickly.  how could a VBA code assist?

Comment: @Danielle Sutton: Even if it is only yourself, accessing ONE file in the cloud seems easier than trying to sync 2 files afterwards. If multiuser ready, it should not matter if you forget to close the file (please double-check). Some time ago I utilized the VBA event handler to create a backup each time a user seved, just to make sure no data is lost after accidental deletion (in this case, one always had the backup from the previous save procedure). It might also be possible to utilize some time-based events, but this would be a separate question.